# How can I change color of a star icon in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am using Kivy and Kivymd. I have a little truble.
I have an app.

1. User adds a topic to favorite.
2. User goes to Favorite screen.
3. User removes a topic from favorite.
4. User comes back to Main Screen.In this part I have a truble because color of icon has to change a color by default, but it doesn't happen. I don't know way. In TopicCard/**init** my condition is working but color of my Icon is not changing.

```
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
kivy.require('1.11.1')
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.utils import rgba
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

data = [
    {'id': 1, 'topic': 'Article 1', 'favorite': False}
]

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class TopicCard(MDCard):
    id = NumericProperty()
    topic = StringProperty()
    favorite_topic = BooleanProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TopicCard, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        if self.favorite_topic == True:
            self.iconButton = MDIconButton(
            id='stars',
            icon='star',
            theme_text_color='Custom',
            text_color=rgba('#E91E63')
        )
            self.iconButton.text_color = rgba('#E91E63')
            print('it is true')

        elif self.favorite_topic == False:
            self.iconButton = MDIconButton(
            id='stars',
            icon='star',
            theme_text_color='Custom',
            text_color=rgba('#000000')
        )
            self.iconButton.text_color = rgba('#000000')
            print('it is false')

        self.add_widget(self.iconButton)
        self.iconButton.bind(on_release=lambda x:self.favorite(self.id, self.topic))
#
    def favorite(self, id, topic):
        if self.favorite_topic == True:
            self.iconButton.text_color = rgba('#000000')
            self.favorite_topic = False
            for d in data:
                if d['id'] == id:
                    d['favorite'] = False
        else:
            self.iconButton.text_color = rgba('#E91E63')
            self.favorite_topic = True
            for d in data:
                if d['id'] == id:
                    d['favorite'] = True

class FavoriteScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        for x in data:
            card = TopicCard(id=x.get('id'), topic=x.get('topic'), favorite_topic=x.get('favorite'))
            self.ids.box.add_widget(card)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.ids.box.clear_widgets()
        Main()

class Main(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_cards)

    def create_cards(self, i):
        print(data, ' < --- Create_Cards')
        for x in data:
            card = TopicCard(id=x.get('id'), topic=x.get('topic'), favorite_topic=x.get('favorite'))
            self.ids.box.add_widget(card)

class Examp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('demo.kv')
        self.window_manager = WindowManager()
        return self.window_manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Examp().run()
```

This is my *demo.kv* file.

```
<WindowManager>
    Main:
        id: main
        name: 'main'
    FavoriteScreen:
        id: favorite
        name: 'favorite'

<FavoriteScreen>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbarBack:
        ScrollView:
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 50
                size_hint_y: None
                orientation: 'vertical'
                height: self.minimum_height
                MDList:
                    spacing: 15
                    id: box

<MDToolbarBack@MDToolbar>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.theme_cls.standard_increment
    padding: '5dp'
    spacing: '12dp'

    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'arrow-left'
        pos_hint: {'center_y': .5}
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 1,1,1,1
        on_press: app.window_manager.current = 'main'

    MDLabel:
        text: 'App'
        theme_text_color: 'Custom'
        text_color: 1,1,1,1

<TopicCard>
    size_hint: 1, None
    padding: 30
    MDLabel:
        text: root.topic

<Main>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'App'
            MDFlatButton:
                theme_text_color: 'Custom'
                text_color: 1,1,1,1
                font_size: '18dp'
                text: 'Go to Favorite'
                pos_hint: {'center_y': .5}
                on_press: app.window_manager.current = 'favorite'

        ScrollView:
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 50
                size_hint_y: None
                orientation: 'vertical'
                height: self.minimum_height
                MDList:
                    spacing: 15
                    id: box
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it like this.
I am sure there is better way to do it, but anyways it is working fine for me.
I changed my Main class this way.

```
class Main(Screen):

    get_ids = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_cards)

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        if self.get_ids != None:
            for x in data:
                card = TopicCard(id=x.get('id'), topic=x.get('topic'), favorite_topic=x.get('favorite'))
                self.ids.box.add_widget(card)
        print('I am from on_pre_enter')

    def create_cards(self, i):
        self.get_ids = self.ids.box
        for x in data:
            card = TopicCard(id=x.get('id'), topic=x.get('topic'), favorite_topic=x.get('favorite'))
            self.ids.box.add_widget(card)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.ids.box.clear_widgets()

class Examp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('demo.kv')
        self.window_manager = WindowManager()
        return self.window_manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Examp().run()
```